# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, rest, android-volley

I created a REST API for my application to connect to the MYSQL database by hosting at infinityfree, my website already has an SSL certificate which I got directly from infinityfree.
But when I use the REST API in my android studio project and run the application this error appears:

```
D/Linux: [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.abiapp.androidukk :443 
W/System.err: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkUtility.shouldRetryException(NetworkUtility.java:173)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:145)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:132)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.processRequest(NetworkDispatcher.java:111)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:90)
W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.SSLUtils.toSSLHandshakeException(SSLUtils.java:362)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.convertException(ConscryptEngine.java:1134)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1089)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:876)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:747)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.unwrap(ConscryptEngine.java:712)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.processDataFromSocket(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:849)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$SSLInputStream.access$100(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:722)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.doHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:238)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket.startHandshake(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:217)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:196)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:153)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.io.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:116)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:186)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:128)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:97)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:289)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:232)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:465)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:131)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:262)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:219)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:30)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.createOutputStream(HurlStack.java:319)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBody(HurlStack.java:301)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.addBodyIfExists(HurlStack.java:285)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.setConnectionParametersForRequest(HurlStack.java:257)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.executeRequest(HurlStack.java:89)
W/System.err:     at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:104)
W/System.err:   ... 3 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrustedRecursive(TrustManagerImpl.java:661)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:510)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:428)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.getTrustedChainForServer(TrustManagerImpl.java:356)
W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.NetworkSecurityTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(NetworkSecurityTrustManager.java:94)
W/System.err:     at android.security.net.config.RootTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(RootTrustManager.java:90)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngineSocket$2.checkServerTrusted(ConscryptEngineSocket.java:161)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:250)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.verifyCertificateChain(ConscryptEngine.java:1644)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.ENGINE_SSL_read_direct(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeSsl.readDirectByteBuffer(NativeSsl.java:568)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextDataDirect(ConscryptEngine.java:1095)
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptEngine.readPlaintextData(ConscryptEngine.java:1079)
W/System.err:   ... 29 more
W/System.err: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:   ... 42 more
I/InputTransport: Create ARC handle: 0x78a4e05920
D/ViewRootImpl[StartActivity]: msg2 update new insets InsetsState: {mDisplayFrame=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340), mSources= { InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_STATUS_BAR, mFrame=[0,0][1080,96], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][1080,96], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_GESTURES, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_TAPPABLE_ELEMENT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,96], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_LEFT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][-2147483648,2340], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_TOP_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,0][1080,96], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_RIGHT_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[2147483647,0][1080,2340], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_BOTTOM_DISPLAY_CUTOUT, mFrame=[0,2147483647][1080,2340], mVisible=true}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_IME, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=false}, InsetsSource: {mType=ITYPE_SEC_IME, mFrame=[0,0][0,0], mVisible=false} }
```

I use the Volley library to access the REST API, before when I hosted the REST API on 000webhost everything was running normally, what's wrong?

Comment: `Trust anchor for certification path not found.` usually means you are using a self-signed certificate on the server or the CA that has issued the certificate is unknown to Android. You can use https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to test a server for common SSL mistakes (the HTTPS server if there is one running). BTW: It is usually a bad idea to directly communicate to a MySQL database from within an Android app. Everybody who has the APK can then extract the database credentials and access the database on raw level making all modifications allowed by the credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bypass SSL, try this code:

```
private static void enableHTTPS() {
    try {
        TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{new X509TrustManager() {
            public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                return new X509Certificate[0];
            }

            @Override
            public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }

            @Override
            public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {
            }
        }};

        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                return true;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ignored) {
    }
}
```

If not, try to add the certificate to your JDK using this command:

```
keytool -import -alias joe -file mycert.cer -keystore mycerts -storepass changeit
```

Comment: Thank you, I've bypassed it, and it turns out that web hosting doesn't allow hosting REST APIs on their web hosting so my REST API data can't be retrieved.

Comment: You're welcome, so you need to change your hosting, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your ssl certificate is not trusted. Either correct your ssl configuration on server, or bypass ssl errors in your app (not recommended).

Answer (score -1):

Depends on server capability. You can try Heliohost built-in ssl.

I had an account on infinityfree too. I heard they can fix your ssl problems if you upgrade your account into paid plan.